# Remove extra new line from cygwin command line

Tags: windows, cygwin

After opening the cygwin in windows we can see the current user and path in one line and the next command need to type in the next line.

```
user@mycomputer /cygdrive/e/folder 
$ |
```

Every time when I press the enter key it will go down by two line

```
 user@mycomputer /cygdrive/e/folder 
 $
 user@mycomputer /cygdrive/e/folder 
 $
 user@mycomputer /cygdrive/e/folder 
 $
 user@mycomputer /cygdrive/e/folder 
 $ |
```

What I need to do is remove that extra line and same like windows command prompt next command need to type in-front (or end) of the first line. Something like this

```
C:\Users\myname>_
```

So even I press enter key multiple times cursor only jump one line per time.

```
C:\Users\myname>
C:\Users\myname>
C:\Users\myname>
C:\Users\myname>
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: What's in your `$PS1`? Try `echo "[$PS1]"`.

Comment: This is $PS1 `[\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prompt contains a newline. Remove the `\n` from `PS1`.

Search through your startup files (`.profile`, `.bashrc` etc.) where the variable is assigned to and make the change permanent there.

Comment: This is what I wanted `PS1="\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]> "`

Comment: export `PS1="\e[0;32m\h \W> \e[m"` for  `HOSTHAME />`

Comment: go to C:\cygwin64\home\[username]\.bashrc and add `PS1='\e[0;32m\h \W> \e[m'` at end of the file.